# How to set up react and nodeJS on your local machine(npm error)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new in React and nodeJS and I have some problems with webpack and npm. I've tried to configure my localhost based on this tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

When I write into the cmd: "npm start" it throws me the following message(on the picture). I've installed webpack but it says it doesn't recognise it. And what is a "weird error" by the way? 
Can you give me some links, where I can properly config my machine?

[image]

My webpack.config.js file:

```
 var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
    path:'./',
    filename: 'index.js',
    },

   devServer: {
     inline: true,
     port: 8080
   },

   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2016', 'react']
        }
     }
    ]
   }
  }

  module.exports = config;
```

package.json file:

```
   {
    "name": "reactApp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "BSD"
   }
```

Comment: have you installed webpack-dev-server globally or locally?

Comment: I 've installed it globally!

Comment: from your command line, at the root of your project, what do you get when you run `webpack-dev-server --open` ?

Comment: It doesn't even recognise the command. It says, the given name cannot be recognised as internal or external command ...

Comment: Whatever I do it can't recognise it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is in Hungarian I think, but from what I see I guess the system isn't able to find webpack-dev-server.

Try to install it locally using `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`. Make sure it is there inside `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`.  If your console says it can't find the command, try running `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`

Refer to this for more info regarding webpack-dev-server installation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server

==================

edit: regarding the new error, as it says in the console, you need to add the suffix `-loader` to `babel`in your webpack.config.js

```
 var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
    path:'./',
    filename: 'index.js',
    },

   devServer: {
     inline: true,
     port: 8080
   },

   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2016', 'react']
        }
     }
    ]
   }
  }

  module.exports = config;
```

Comment: It's a very nice and clear guide, but despite it still not working. I'm getting mad :(

Comment: have you installed webpack-dev-server locally? did you find the file inside `node_modules\.bin` ? what do u get when u run `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` ?

Comment: this is a new error, inside of your webpack.config.js, change `babel` to `babel-loader`

Comment: It finally works. Thank you for the efforts you made :)